# Cannot bring data from Firestore in Dialogflow Fulfillment (In-line Editor)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using **Dialogflow** to build an *Action for Google Assistant*. Everything works, except the Fulfillment of my intent.

I am using the *Inline Editor* (Powered by Cloud Functions for Firebase) to fulfill the intent. My function in itself runs - since I can send text to the assistant from the function.

But for some reason, code execution never enters the the function that fetches data from my `Collection` on **Firebase Firestore** - although it ***does*** execute commands before and after.

Here is the code in my `index.js`.

```js
'use strict';
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
let db = admin.firestore();
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

app.intent('INTENT', (conv, {ENTITY}) => {
    conv.add("Hello.");         //THIS IS DISPLAYED

    db.collection("COLLECTION").orderBy("FIELD", "desc").get().then(snapshot => {
        conv.add("Hey!");       //THIS IS NOT DISPLAYED
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        conv.add("Hi?");        //NOR IS THIS       
    });
        conv.add("Hmm...");     //NEITHER THIS
    }).catch(error => {
        conv.add('Error!');     //NOT EVEN THIS
    });

    conv.add("Bye.");           //THIS IS DISPLAYED TOO
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Clearly, this shows that execution never really entered the `db...` block, and hence the function didn't even throw any error.

Here are the logs from Firebase.

```
Function execution started
```

```
Billing account not configured...
```

```
Warning, estimating Firebase Config based on GCLOUD_PROJECT. Initializing firebase-admin may fail
```

```
Request {...}
```

```
Headers {...}
```

```
Conversation {...}
```

```
Response {...}
```

```
Function execution took 1681 ms, finished with status code: 200
```

I know that the `firestore` function fetches data asynchronously, but there 
seems no way I could execute anything even inside its `.then(...)` block.

I also tried `return`ing a `Promise` from the `.then(...)` block, and using a second `.then(...)` with it - which again didn't work.

```js
var fetch = db.collection("COLLECTION").orderBy("FIELD", "desc").get().then(snapshot => {
    conv.add("Hey!");                    //NOT DISPLAYED
    var responseArr = [];
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        conv.add("Hi?");                 //NOT DISPLAYED  
        responseArr.push(doc);  
    });
    conv.add("Hmm...");                  //NOT DISPLAYED
    return Promise.resolve(responseArr);
}).then(fetch => {
    conv.add("Here?");                   //NOT DISPLAYED
}).catch(error => {
    conv.add('Error!');                  //NOT DISPLAYED
});
```

Finally, I also tried putting the `firestore` function in a separate `function`, like this.

```js
function getData(){
    return db.collection("COLLECTION").orderBy("FIELD", "desc").get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            ...    
        });

        return data;                //Manipulated from above. 'data' can be a string.
    }).catch(error => {
           return error;
    });
}

app.intent('INTENT', (conv, {ENTITY}) => {
    conv.add("Hello.");         //THIS IS DISPLAYED

    conv.add(getData());        //THIS IS NOT DISPLAYED

    conv.add("Bye.");           //THIS IS DISPLAYED
});
```

Comment: As it said - if the other answer doesn't address your question, go ahead and [ask a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Editing the question isn't enough, but if the other answer doesn't help - go ahead and re-ask, clarifying what part of the other answer didn't make sense.

Comment: @Prisoner Sure, thanks! It seems you answered the *original* question - it would be great if you could help.

Comment: What about it doesn't answer your question?

Comment: @Prisoner I read a couple answers more, which were also coincidentally written by you. With that reference, I `return`ed a `Promise` in the `.then(...)` block, and added a second `.then(...)` block - yet there's no difference.

Comment: Re-post the question with what you've tried and I'll provide a longer answer.

Comment: @Prisoner I have updated the answer. Kindly tell me if there's any thing I need to provide.

Comment: @Prisoner I believe, since you have the [gold] `actions-on-google` badge, you can single handedly re-open the question. Reposting would duplicate my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing an asynchronous operation (the call to `get()`), but you're not returning a Promise from the Intent Handler itself. The library requires you to return a Promise so it knows that there is an async operation taking place.

Returning a Promise from *inside* the `then()` portion isn't enough - that doesn't return a value from the handler, it just returns a value that is passed to the next `then()` function or (if it was the last one) as the return value of the entire Promise chain.

In your original code, this can be done just by returning the `get().then().catch()` chain. Something like this as your first line:

```
return db.collection("COLLECTION").orderBy("FIELD", "desc").get() // etc etc
```

In your second example, the `fetch` in your `then()` block is not the `fetch` that you think it is, and only confuses matters. Structured that way, you need to return the `fetch` from the `let` assignment.

Your third example is more complicated. The line

```
conv.add(getData());
```

doesn't even seem like it would work, on the surface, because it is returning a Promise, but you can't add a promise to the `conv` object. You would need to rewrite that part as

```
return getData()
  .then( data => conv.add( data ) );
```

But that doesn't address how the "Bye" line would work. If you actually wanted "Bye" after the data, you would have to include it as part of the `then()` block.

In short, when dealing with async data, you need to

1. Make sure you understand how Promises work and make sure all async work is done using Promises.
2. Add all your data inside the `then()` portion of a Promise
3. Return a Promise correctly

Comment: Thank you so much! `return getData().then( data => conv.add( data ) );` worked for me so well! 
Promises are really a nightmare for me...